# How to destroy the previous activity but splash and home activity is not included when moving to the next activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have 6 open activities (see the image below).

[image]

But what I want to happen is when the user proceeds to `orderDetailsActivity` it will destroy all the previous activity but not the `splashActivity` and `homeActivity`.
[image]

So the user can easily move back to `homeActivity`. And please note that I want to use `finish();` when moving back to `homeActivity` only.

[image]

**Note:** The user can move back and forth from `homeActivty`, `cartActivity` and `checkoutActivity` so destroying those activities right after moving to another one is not possible.

Comment: add Finish() after Intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move from `Checkout Activity` to `Loading Activity` you can simply call finish() to destroy the `checkout activity`.

In the onBackPressed of `Loading Activity` you can do like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Loading.this , Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.ACITIVTIY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);  
finish();
```

This would redirect you to the `Home Activity` (previous instance) and will clear the activities which are on top of the stack. Therefore, what you want is achieved!

For more info: [Understand Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack)

### Update:

If you want the same thing to happen in the `Order Details Activity`, you just put the code in `onBackPressed` of `order details`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (OrderDetails.this , Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.ACITIVTIY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);  
finish();
```

Comment: You are cool! But there are pointers that I want to clear out. First is the loading activity, there's no button in that activity it was all process on adding cart items to transaction's table/collection and after that It will automatically intent or move to `orderDetailsActivity` so buyer can see his/her purchased. Second is the back button is in `orderDetailsActivity` and not in `loadingActivity`.

Comment: What happens if the user presses the back button in the loading activity? You want to redirect to the Home activity, right? And the same with OrderDetails activity?

Comment: `loadingActivity` is just an activity with gif preview. It does not have any back button process.

Comment: I will edit my question because It was a bit misleading.

Comment: You just put the code which I answered, in the orderDetails Activity instead of loading Activity.

Comment: Yup my bad. Sorry I didn't get it at first. Your answer is the correct one. I will acknowledge your answer. Thank you!!!

Comment: Happy to be helpful ;)

Comment: Intent.ACITIVTIY_SINGLE_TOP is not working now. instead of it we can use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use finish()

In your navigation line you add finish()

```
 Intent it = new Intent (currentActivity.this,MovingActivity.class);
 startActivity(it);
 finish();
```

and which activity not want to destroy their you add only

```
 Intent it = new Intent (currentActivity.this,MovingActivity.class);
 startActivity(it);
```

Comment: This is a nice idea but when the user moved from `cartActivity` to `checkoutActivity` they can still move back to `cartActivity`.

Comment: Means you need to go and you don't want to go

Comment: can you please elaborate your situation.